# Linux - Serial Communication with RS485

Tags: linux, bash, communication, rs485

I have been trying to send the bytes (in order): `2201`, `2211` etc. to my Arduino board, which I've connected to my computer, using a USB to RS485 adapter.

However, when I connect it yo my computer, whenever I try to send `2201` to my Arduino, using the command `echo 2 > /dev/ttyUSB0;echo 2 > /dev/ttyUSB0;echo 0 > /dev/ttyUSB0;echo 1 > /dev/ttyUSB0`, it sometimes works, turning the LED on normally as it should, but other times it just doesn't, displaying `bash: /dev/ttyUSB0: Input/output error`.

[image: Screenshot]

If you have any way of getting through this, that'd be great. Also, please let me know if there's any better command than `echo X > /dev/ttyUSB0` to send data to my Arduino. I'm new to serial communication, so I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.